# Replacing a part of file path by a string in c

Tags: c

```
FILE *fptr1;
char str[10];

fptr1=fopen("D:\\New Folder\\test.txt","rb")
//Now I want to replace text.txt with my string.Just want to know the syntax :/
```

Comment: `Now I want to replace text.txt with my string` but where `text.txt`?

Comment: In that file path ...D\\NewFolder\\TEST.TXT[want to replace this by STR] ....only TEST.txt not D:\\New Folder\\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such way that you can directly edit what `fptr1` contains.

```
FILE *fptr1;
char str[10];
//char fileName[50] = "test.txt";
char path[500] = strcat("D:\\New Folder\\","test.txt");
fptr1=fopen(path,"rb");
```

Comment: thanks ....it worked...couldnt think of strcat....silly me :)

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to understand, what do you need. May be you are looking for something like this:

```
char str[] = "D:\\New Folder\\test.txt";
FILE *fptr1 = fopen(str, "rb");
```